# CCTransitionPageTurn not working after using opengl

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using CCTansitionPageTurn to flip between scenes.  It works fine for most scenes, but I have a coloring scene that draws with gl.  After coloring begins, CCTransitionPageTurn does not work for any scene transition, even those that worked fine before. (I can still move to another scene just fine, but the page turn effect is broken).

I think it may have to do with altering the gl state before the transition is called, but restoring the default gl state didn't work.  There's potentially a lot of places in the code where the problem is, but here's some code where I'm playing with gl.

```
/* ColoringGameScene : CCScene, which handles drawing menus and other cool UI things */

// In init
CCLayerColor *layer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255)];
[self addChild:layer];
TouchDraw *drawObj = [TouchDraw node];
[drawObj setDrawPoints:_drawPoints];
[layer addChild:drawObj z:999];

// In -(void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *) touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
// drawPoints, an array of points to draw is updated.  drawObj has a reference to this array


/* In TouchDraw : CCNode, which handles gl drawing */

// In init
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT);
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT);
glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT,GL_NICEST);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_BLEND_COLOR); 
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glLineWidth(8);
glPointSize(8);

// elsewhere

-(void)drawCircle:(CGPoint)center radius:(float)r arc:(float)a line:(NSUInteger)segs lineToCenter: (BOOL)drawLineToCenter
{
int additionalSegment = 1;
if (drawLineToCenter)
    additionalSegment++;

const float coef = 2.0f * (float)M_PI/segs;

GLfloat *vertices = calloc( sizeof(GLfloat)*2*(segs+2), 1);
if( ! vertices )
    return;

for(NSUInteger i=0;i<=segs;i++)
{
    float rads = i*coef;
    GLfloat j = r * cosf(rads + a) + center.x;
    GLfloat k = r * sinf(rads + a) + center.y;

    vertices[i*2] = j * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
    vertices[i*2+1] =k * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
}
vertices[(segs+1)*2] = center.x * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
vertices[(segs+1)*2+1] = center.y * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);  
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, (GLsizei) segs+additionalSegment);

// restore default state
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);    

free( vertices );
}

-(void)draw
{
[super draw];

    if ([drawPoints count])
{
        for(int i = 0; i < [drawPoints count]; i += 4)
        {
            CGPoint point0 = CGPointFromString([drawPoints objectAtIndex:i]);
            CGPoint point1 = CGPointFromString([drawPoints objectAtIndex:i+1]);
            CGPoint point2 = CGPointFromString([drawPoints objectAtIndex:i+2]);
            CGPoint point3 = CGPointFromString([drawPoints objectAtIndex:i+3]);

            glColor4f(255.0f/255.0f, 0.0f/255.0f, 0.0f/255.0f, 1.0f); // Red
            glLineWidth(8);
            glPointSize(8);

            // various calls to drawCirle and ccDrawCubicBezier

            //default
            glColor4f(0.0f/255.0f, 0.0f/255.0f, 0.0f/255.0f, 0.0f);
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if more code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm beginer in openGL, but as I know, OpenGL settings are same for all your program. Some code  of your own drawing should change something in this settings. This may be the reason of your eshue. I cant tell you more, but you should work on this question.